# Property or method "navigationLinks" is not defined on the instance but referenced during render. Make sure that this property is reactive

Tags: vuex, vuex-modules

Am stack in calling data from vuex module to component.

Am calling Navigation links where I have created a module `navigation.js`. I have imported the module in the main store.

Am using the getters to call the data in the component.

My navigation component looks like this

```
<template>
  <nav>
    <ul>
      <li v-for="link in navigationLinks" :key="link.label">
        <router-link :to="link.route">{{ link.label }}</router-link>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
</template>
<script>
import { mapGetters, mapActions } from 'vuex'
import store from '@/store';
import navigation from '@/store/navigation';

  export default {
  name: 'Navbar',
  data: {
    
  },
  computed: {
    ...mapGetters(['navigationLinks'])
  }
}
```

In my main `store.js`

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import Vuex from 'vuex'
import auth from './auth'
import navigation from './navigation'
Vue.use(Vuex)

export default new Vuex.Store({
  state: {
  },
  getters: {
  },
  mutations: {
  },
  actions: {
  },
  modules: {
    auth,
    navigation
  }
})
```

In my `navigation.js` I have

```
const state = {
  links: [
    { label: 'Home', route: '/', icon: 'home' },
    { label: 'About', route: '/about', icon: 'info' },
    { label: 'Contact', route: '/contact', icon: 'envelope' },
  ]
}

const getters = {
  navigationLinks: state => state.links
}

export default {
  state,
  getters
}
```

Comment: You have 2 of them defined in your first snippet.

Comment: Do you still have the error? Where is it coming from? A typo maybe?

Comment: yes still experiencing it

Comment: Where is it coming from?